# Difference between Session("foo") is "test" and Cstr(Session("foo") = "test"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to know the difference between the following.

```
Difference between Session("foo") is "test" and Cstr(Session("foo")) = "test"
```

I understand the second one is casting to string. The thing I don't get is, one one page, when I tried,

```
if Session("foo") is "test" Then
    Do something
```

This worked on one page. On some pages the do something does not get executed even if Session("foo") is "test". On the other hand Cstr(Session("foo")) = "test" always works. Why is the difference. Out of the two, which suits better for convention?

Comment: CStr(Session("foo") = "test" is the usual case you would expect to see.  Session("foo") Is "test" not as common (I've never seen anyone do string comparisons this way, and I've seen a *lot* of VB code).  Strings are a little unusual since they are not treated as strict as other reference types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Is** operator determines if two object references refer to the same object. However, **it does not perform value comparisons**. If object1 and object2 both refer to the exact same object instance, result is True; if they do not, result is False. [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx)

So in your case you need to convert the object of the Session to string before you want to compare it with another string value type.

**To Answer to your next question**

You can set a property in your page instead of repeating that code several times on your page like below:

```
Public Property MyValue() As String
  Get
    Return Session("MyValue").ToString()
  End Get
  Set
    Session("MyValue") = value
  End Set
End Property
```

Now you can Set and Get this value anywhere inside your page, like this:

```
MyValue = "This is my value"     'set a value

Dim message As String = MyValue  'get a value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ali. If I am using the same session variable multiple times in the page, should I create a local variable? Becauase, seeing Cstr(Session("somthing")) does not look clean. I am not sure to use a local variable because, I know the variables get resetted on page post back. Which approach would you follow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a Property that sets or gets the Session value.

Comment: @OneFineDay Thanks for the reply. Would the property value get resetted after the page post back? I understand how page post back works, but I am not sure if the property will still hold the session value

Comment: No, because you still set the value of a property inside a session, it won't get lost. I've updated for you.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of Session is Object.

The Is operator compares the object references of two objects.

The = operator compares the values stored in two objects.

Since you want to check to see if the session has a particular name, you want to compare the values of two strings, you need to use the = operator.

When you use the Is operator to compare object references, it checks to see of the two references are pointing to the same string instance.  But, Is will evaluate to false if you compare two separate object instances, even if both instances contain the same string value.